# Getting rid of the Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have tried getting rid of the action bar but I keep getting this error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//I added this
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Manifest file

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >//Changed this
```

I am using the theme below

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I have read many posts and tried them but the app keeps crashing.
Plaese help.

Comment: Please copy the full stacktrace and not only the message in the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another parent theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent=Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

instead of "DarkActionBar".

Comment: Your welcome. You can also set this as an accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

and you Theme like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your theme in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

In manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".InitializationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar" >
```